# HTTP Request always end up cancelled since last iOS upgrade

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code that was working really great until now:

```
let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral,
                         delegate: URLSessionPinningDelegate(),
                         delegateQueue: nil)

let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
    completion(data, response, error)
}
task.resume()
```

It's running perfectly in the application in production. But recently I tried to make a new build and it **always** end up in error with the operation cancelled. The request is never made to the server (I have zero connection log on apache2).

I tried to look on what changed but couldn't found anything. Do somebody know something about this?

Comment: Perhaps, since you are creating a URLSession rather than using `URLSession.shared`, the session is going out of scope and being deallocated. Have you tried storing a strong reference to your session?

Comment: @daltonclaybrook nice idea, I tried pushing references in a static array to test your theory, and sadly it didn't work better...

Comment: Will you share the full error message reported by the session?

Comment: @daltonclaybrook there's actually no error message, it just end up cancelled!

Comment: So the completion block does not get called at all?

Comment: @daltonclaybrook it does. data is nil, response is nil, error is cancelled ^^' .

Comment: @Nek Did you ever find a solution? I have the same problem now...

Comment: @OliverEichhorn sorry, we ended up with crashing the app and rebuild from the ground... But while debugging the issue I figured out that the issue was probably something asynchronous.